# local phpMyAdmin needs login

Tags: phpmyadmin

In my local phpMyAdmin I have to log to system and I lose session after some time , though in my config /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
there are rows :

```
/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
 * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
```

Have I to set more options to enter to phpMyAdmin without login?

> Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu) phpMyAdmin 
>   Version information: 4.0.10deb1

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']    = 'config'; // instead of cookie
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']     = '1234'; // use your MySQL root password
```

In my experience, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

As that comment says (and as described in the phpMyAdmin documentation), the AllowNoPassword line allows you to log in to accounts that have no password. For instance, by default many MySQL installations use the username root with a blank password; by default phpMyAdmin does not allow this because it would be a big security hole on a public-facing server. The AllowNoPassword directive changes that behavior; it doesn't have anything to do with whether you actually have to log in or how long your session lasts.

If you wish to not be prompted at all when connecting, you can use [auth_type config](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/auth_types). Combined with hardcoding your username and password (the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` directives), you'll never be prompted. Those are only used with auth_type config.

Anyway, it does not sound like that's your problem at all, since you specifically mentioned losing the session after some time. Session expiration is controlled by two factors; an overall PHP limit and one within phpMyAdmin. The phpMyAdmin limit is controlled by the [`$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_LoginCookieValidity) directive, but it's limited by your PHP setting [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime).

So to increase the length of a session, you need to increase the LoginCookieValidity directive, but if you increase that above what your global PHP gc_maxlifetime is, you'll also have to increase that to match.